# WSL2 interop issue causes premature exit from read loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Summary

Using read loop that runs a windows executable in WSL shell script causes it to exit the loop after the first iteration.

#### Details

I've been quite baffled by what appears to be an interoperability issue with running windows executables from a shell script in WSL2. The following while loop should print 3 lines but it will only print "line 1". It has been tested on Ubuntu 20.04 in dash, bash, and zsh.

```
while read -r line; do
       powershell.exe /C "echo \"${line}\""
done << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

This issue also occurs when reading lines from a file instead of a heredoc even if that file has windows line endings. Note that if powershell were changed to `/bin/bash` or any other native executable this would print 3 lines. Also powershell could be replaced with any windows executable cmd.exe, explorer.exe, etc and it would still only run the first iteration. This appears to be a problem with read specifically since this loop will work fine.

```
for line in "line 1" "line 2" "line 3"
do
    powershell.exe /C "echo \"${line}\""
done
```

#### Work-around

Thanks to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/epvd2r/seeking_help_with_interop_issues_in_bash_running/) post I have discovered a work around is to pipe through a dummy command: `echo "" | cmd.exe /C  "echo \"${line}\""`. A note about this fix is that only piping seems to work. Redirecting the output or running it through another layer of bash does not: `/bin/bash -c "cmd.exe /C \"echo  ${line}\""`. I am partially posting this for improved visibility for anyone having this issue in the future, but I am still curious if anyone has any insight as to why this issue exists (perhaps due to line endings?). Thank you!

Comment: **a windows executable in WSL shell script causes it to exit the loop after the first iteration.** That is a common error on files/data that has windows line endings aka carriage returns.

Comment: I encounter this issue when the file has unix line endings as well

Comment: It could be that power_shell is reading from `stdin`, try using a different `fd` in the `while` + `read` loop. DIsclaimer, I don't use power shell. Question is, why use bash at all? Can't power shell do a loop?

Comment: Well it still breaks when using the heredoc as the input data as in my first example so I don't think it would be possible for the file descriptor to be conflicting in that case? I don't use powershell either for the record this is just an example it could be any windows native executable

Comment: There’s a similar problem using `ssh` in shell scripts; you need to give it the `-n` option to prevent it from reading stdin. Does the powershell `-NonInteractive` option help?

Comment: Nope still breaks. It's worth noting though that the issue occurs even with programs that (shouldn't?) be reading from `stdin`. For example changing powershell to `explorer.exe` would open only 1 window instead of 3 as expected.

Comment: My explanation below is long enough even before covering the `explorer.exe` example ;-), but it's likely that WSL still calls CMD (or some intermediary, interop Windows process) when calling *any* `.exe`.  So I'm not surprised that non-console, non-stdin-consuming commands still "gobble" stdin.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! It seemed so strange and I had great difficulty finding any similar issues online so I hope this helps someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short Answer:*

A slightly-improved solution over `echo "" |` is to do a second-redirection from `/dev/null`.  This avoids potential newline issues from the `echo`, but there are other solutions as well:

```
while read -r line; do
       powershell.exe /C "echo \"${line}\"" < /dev/null
done << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

*Explanation:*

Well, you already had a solution, but what you really wanted was the explanation.

Jetchisel and MarkPlotnick are on the right track in the comments.  This appears to be the same root cause (and solution) as in [this question about `ssh`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107800/432493).  To replicate your example with `ssh` (assuming a key in `ssh-agent` so that no password prompt is generated):

```
while read -r line; do
  ssh hostname echo ${line}
  done << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

You will see the same results as with PowerShell -- Only "line 1" displays.

In both cases, the first line goes to the `read` statement, but the subsequent lines are stdin which are consumed by `powershell.exe` (or `ssh`) itself.

You can see this "proven" in PowerShell through a slight modification to your script:

```sh
while read -r line; do
  powershell.exe -c "echo \"--- ${line} ---\"; \$input"
  done << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

Results in:

```
--- line 1 ---
line 2
line 3
```

The follow-up question is, IMHO, why `bash` doesn't have this issue.  The answer is that PowerShell seems to *always* consume whatever stdin is available at the time of invocation and adds it to the `$input` magic variable.  Bash, on the other hand, does not consume the additional stdin until explicitly asked:

```sh
while read -r line; do
  bash -c "echo --- \"${line}\" ---; cat /dev/stdin"
  done << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

Generates the same results as the previous PowerShell example:

```
--- line 1 ---
line 2
line 3
```

Ultimately, the main solution with PowerShell is to force a second indirection which is consumed before your *desired* input.  `echo "" |` can do this, but be careful:

```sh
while read -r line; do
  echo "" | powershell.exe -c "echo \"--- ${line} ---\"; \$input" 
  done << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

Results in:

```
--- line 1 ---

--- line 2 ---

--- line 3 ---
```

`< /dev/null` doesn't have this issue, but you could also handle it with `echo -n "" |` instead.